# How to have CRichEditView combined with MDI

Tags: windows, mfc

CRichEditView (+ ~Doc and ~CntrItem) combined with MDI worked in a legacy MFC project (1998), but not anymore with the latest (11) version of MFC, using Visual Studio 2012 C++ professional. 
Apparently, the CRichEditView.m_lpRichEditOle remains zeroNull0nada.
The same happens when I try to change the derivation from CDocument class in the MDI sample from MSDN (MDIDocvw) into CRichEditDoc class (and corresponding views and controlItems).
I need to know whether this is something definite, decided by Ms, or some misunderstanding here.
I might be happy as well with TabbedDI.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to convert some old application for VS 2012, convert other MDI application to use rich edit functionality or you have a problem with the application created in VS 2012?

Comment: Yes, it was a working appication, but old, I only tried to compile it with VC2012, I needed to change all of the string routines. Then the VC2012 compiler seems satisfied, until you start debugging.